# Watch for change of leadership with Apache Curator

Tags: apache-curator

Is there a way I can watch for change of leadership using Curator?  When the leader changes I need all of the followers to know that this has happened so that they can discover who the new leader is. It seems like something standard that the followers would want to know who the leader is, but I cannot work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to watch for changes by using a path cache based on the path of the leader selector.  When an event occurs on this path then their are probably new nodes, less nodes or a new leader.

Comment: I have the same question and was going to down the same path. Looking at the implementation, sorted lexicographically, the first node is the leader (each leader tries to register by creating it's node incrementally). What's not clear is if after one receives an event, can one expect to query the state of zookeeper and see the effects of that event? (Is there some possibility that we receive an event, but the change is not seen until later?)